# Does the data reader change if the underlying data changes?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

Please see the code below:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private _ConString As String
    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        Dim objDR As SqlDataReader
        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand
        Dim objCon As SqlConnection
        Dim id As Integer
        Try
            _ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("TestConnection").ToString
            objCon = New SqlConnection(_ConString)
            objCommand = New SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Person")
            objCommand.Connection = objCon
            objCon.Open()
            objDR = objCommand.ExecuteReader(ConnectionState.Closed)
            Do While objDR.Read
                ProcessPerson(objDR("URN"))
            Loop
            objDR.Close() 'line 16
        Catch ex As Exception
            throw
        Finally

        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Say there are one million records in the Person table and it takes 24 hours to run.  Say I deleted the Person table or updated the data in the table significantly, half way through.  Would it then still process the one million records? Please assume that ProcessPerson does not use the Person table.

I have spent some time Googling this but I have not found an answer.

Comment: From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - "Changes made to a result set by another process or thread while data is being read may be visible to the user of the SqlDataReader. However, the precise behavior is timing dependent." Based on this, I'd say it's possible.

Comment: If you want to control this behavior you should wrap the code in a `TransactionScope` with desired [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.isolationlevel(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Magnus (and those agreeing with that idea of wrapping this in a transaction): If the process takes 24 hours (or even 2 hours) to run, wrapping it in a transaction will cause blocking for other processes. How can you justify locking out all other users for up to a whole day from interacting with this table? Even if other processes do NOLOCK / Read Uncommitted, are you suggesting REPEATABLE READ or even SERIALIZABLE isolation levels and hence preventing other DML operations?

Comment: If it is the `ProcessPerson` function that is taking time then first read the million rows into memory and then run the `ProcessPerson` function

Answer (score 0):

The best way to find out if something will happen under a certain condition is simply to test it out. That beats all documentation since occasionally documentation (whether it be "official" MSDN and/or TechNet pages, blog posts, etc) is incorrect. You already have the app code written so it is a rather simple matter to throw in 1 - 2 million rows into the `[Person]` table. It should be fine if all fields outside of the PK field are the same as you are just testing for a simple effect. Or, maybe sure that at least one field has unique values to make it easier to see if something is missing. Then just run the code that you have posted here and delete a few targeted rows and see if they are there or not in your collection.

After you do that test, look into enabling [Snapshot Isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcbchxcb.aspx) as it is designed to help with this. If this process might take 24 hours then you probably shouldn't be wrapping it in a transaction (well, if you want to keep your job ;-) ).

Another option is to create a stored procedure that does the following:

1. Create temp table
2. INSERT into temp table SELECT query
3. SELECT * FROM temp table

That does separate out and hence preserve your result set for as long as it takes for the app to read it. But it also duplicates the full result set in [tempdb] whereas Snapshot Isolation:

- only uses the space it needs, which will be much less space than the full result set if the rows aren't changing that much, and
- prevents blocking while the initial query is running, which might still happen while populating the temp table